# Possible logical error while creating a custom List data structure

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm trying to make a custom data-structure, most similar to a list, for an assignment.
I have made the class Node:

```
 class Node {   
  int data;  
  Node nextNode = null; 

  public Node(int data) {
      this.data=data;  
      }
 }
```

and the class DataStructure:

```
public class DataStructure {
    private Node previousNode;
    private Node StartingNode;
    private boolean isEmpty = true;

    public void AddNode(int data) {
        if(isEmpty) {
            isEmpty = false;
            StartingNode = new Node(data);
            previousNode = StartingNode;
        }
        else {
            previousNode.nextNode = new Node(data);
            previousNode = previousNode.nextNode;
        }
    }

    private boolean isFirst = true;
    int max = 0;
    public int getMaxData(Node d) {
        if(isFirst) {
            isFirst = false;
            max = d.data;
        }
        else {
            if(d.data > max)
                max = d.data;
            if(d.nextNode != null)
                getMaxData(d.nextNode);
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

When I try to run an example of the above the list is not created correctly (from what I can tell). I've been thinking that it maybe has something to do with the garbage collection but I believe the node objects are still active as they are referenced by the nextNode variable.

This is the main method that runs the example:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
        DataStructure list = new DataStructure();
        list.AddNode(5);
        list.AddNode(15);
        list.AddNode(12);
        list.AddNode(3);        

        System.out.println(list.getMaxData(list.StartingNode));
    }
```

Expected result is the number 15 to be printed but I get the first node only(5).
I tried "debugging" by adding a System.out.writeln(d.data) at the start of getMaxData() and I only get 5 printed so I believe the other nodes aren't created.

Comment: Well, your handling of `isFirst` or is it supposed to "flag" the first call of `getMaxData`?

Comment: Well, yes so that I can get a correct max in case the value of data is negative.

Comment: It currently does only one thing: notice it is the first call to `getMaxData` and then only return the value of the node passed and ignore everything else. That's why you get 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is this:

```
if(isFirst) {
    isFirst = false;
    max = d.data;
} else {...}
```

The if will always happen for the first element, and then you just return that value. You can do it with just the else clause:

```
public int getMaxData(Node d) {
    if (d.data > max)
        max = d.data;
    if (d.nextNode != null)
        return getMaxData(d.nextNode);
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Oh you are right. I tried to get around the error "function must return int on all paths" and missed this.

Comment: You should also set `max` to the initial value of `data` in the constructor, so that it works with negative numbers too.